# How to fix the permission problem with Graph Explorer for my own tasks?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph explorer to retrieve my own tasks: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner

But it's returning: "Failure - Status Code 403. Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions."

How can I fix this without having sitting the administrator physically next to me? Besides that I don't know at this moment who this could be anyway.

Why I need those permissions anyway since I'm only requesting my own tasks?

Comment: Has your organization consented to Graph Explorer? You may need to contact your IT department to find out. Graph Explorer will need at least `Group.Read.All` in order to access Planner objects and this requires Admin Consent before any user in the tenant can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no other option than admin consent to  `Group.Read.All`. Finally figured who could to that in the organisation. Still strange you need admin consent for your app to read your own tasks.